# How do I convert an IntPtr to a Stream?

Tags: .net, c++, interop, managed-c++

```
class Foo
{
   static bool Bar(Stream^ stream);
};

class FooWrapper
{
   bool Bar(LPCWSTR szUnicodeString)
   {
       return Foo::Bar(??);
   }
};
```

`MemoryStream` will take a `byte[]` but I'd *like* to do this without copying the data if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can avoid the copy if you use an [`UnmanagedMemoryStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream.aspx) instead (class exists in .NET FCL 2.0 and later). Like `MemoryStream`, it is a subclass of `IO.Stream`, and has all the usual stream operations.

Microsoft's description of the class is:

> Provides access to unmanaged blocks of memory from managed code.

which pretty much tells you what you need to know. Note that `UnmanagedMemoryStream()` is not CLS-compliant.

Comment: Note: this answer only works in unsafe code. If you do not compile with the unsafe flag, you may have better luck by Marshalling the data to a byte array, then wrapping that byte array in a stream. See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/11660831/684852

You need to know the length of the data (number of bytes in the original unicode string at your pointer) though.

For example:

`byte[] dataArray = new byte[dataLength];
Marshal.Copy(szUnicodeString, dataArray, 0, dataLength);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(dataArray);`

Answer (score 0):

If I had to copy the memory, I think the following would work:

```
static Stream^ UnicodeStringToStream(LPCWSTR szUnicodeString)
{
   //validate the input parameter
   if (szUnicodeString == NULL)
   {
      return nullptr;
   }

   //get the length of the string
   size_t lengthInWChars = wcslen(szUnicodeString);  
   size_t lengthInBytes = lengthInWChars * sizeof(wchar_t);

   //allocate the .Net byte array
   array^ byteArray = gcnew array(lengthInBytes);

   //copy the unmanaged memory into the byte array
   Marshal::Copy((IntPtr)(void*)szUnicodeString, byteArray, 0, lengthInBytes);

   //create a memory stream from the byte array
   return gcnew MemoryStream(byteArray);
}
```