# Converting a pointer into a MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

I am trying to fetch a *Device Independent Bitmap* from the clipboard. I am well-aware that this can be done through the Clipboard.GetData function inbuilt in the .NET Framework, but since it is very buggy (as documented many places on the web), I want to use the APIs only.

I have written the following code which works.

```
//i can correctly cast this to a MemoryStream
MemoryStream ms = Clipboard.GetData("DeviceIndependentBitmap") as MemoryStream;
```

But I want to use it with the APIs, which just return a pointer (an IntPtr) that point to the stream somehow. I took a look at the [UnmanagedMemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream.aspx) but fail to understand how to correctly convert an `IntPtr` into that.

Here's my API code (using the [GetClipboardData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API where the `CF_DIB` format is set as its argument).

```
IntPtr p = GetClipboardData(8);
//what do I do from here to get a MemoryStream from this pointer?
```

I'm a bit confused. I already researched it myself, but couldn't come up with something useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you said you can use [`UnmanagedMemoryStream(byte* pointer, long length)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw66yex7.aspx) and to use it you should have a pointer and the length of the bytes. So you can use [`IntPtr.ToPointer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.intptr.topointer.aspx) method to get the pointer, but you should know the length of the memory content.

```
UnmanagedMemoryStream unmanagedmemstream = UnmanagedMemoryStream(p.ToPointer(), 100);
```

There is another method to retrieve an array of bytes, but also here you should know the length of the memory bytes that you want and it is [`Marshal.Copy(IntPtr source, byte[] destination, int startIndex,int length)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[100];
Marshal.Copy(p , buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```